# Pig Latin Test first teaching

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is Pig_Latin of Test first teaching of Ruby. Here is my code. At first, it running and it stuck at 2 consonant but now it don't run anymore.

```
def translate(a)
    if a.split(' ').size > 1
        a.map {|x| pig(x)}.join(' ')
    else
        pig(a)
    end
end

def pig(word)
    vowels = %w(a o i e u)
    alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
    consonant = alphabet - vowels

    if vowels.include? word[0]
        word + 'ay'
    elsif consonant.include? word[0] && word[1]
        word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + 'ay'
   elsif consonant.include? word[0]
        word[1..-1] + word[0] + 'ay'
    else
        word
    end
end
```

I test with rspec and this is what i got

```
(in /Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/Test)
/Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/Test/04_pig_latin/pig_latin_spec.rb:20:in `require': /Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/Test/04_pig_latin/pig_latin.rb:55: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/Test/04_pig_latin/pig_latin_spec.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
/Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S rspec /Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/Test/04_pig_latin/pig_latin_spec.rb -I/Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/Test/04_pig_latin -I/Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/Test/04_pig_latin/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
```

Help me plz!!! Thanks

Problem solved. I was a noob at that time. Thank you guys

Comment: Please add a comment if you're down–voting or requesting to close giving the OP a chance to improve this or the next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pig_latin.rb:55: syntax error`

The error backtrace tells you what's wrong: bad syntax. Check your code carefully. Each `if` statement needs a corresponding `end`. Same with `def`. Classes also need an `end`, as do code blocks starting with `do`.

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it, you haven't terminated your `if`s. Every multiline `if/else` should have a matching `end`.

```
 if ...
     # happens if true
 else
     # happens if false
 end # <== don't forget this
```

Comment: plz takek a look at the update. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't contain any syntax errors when I run it, but you've only shown us 23 lines of code. Your stack trace references line number 55. Show us the full code.

Comment: do u run the same rspec file? Thats all i have. still have syntax errors